# Aquamacs 24.4 color-theme and font color

Tags: emacs

I have the following code in my preferences.el file:

```
(color-theme-sanityinc-solarized-dark)
(set-default-font "Consolas-18")
```

It *almost* works. The color-theme loads and changes most of the colors to those of the solarized theme; however the font is changed to almost-unreadable black. The weird part is that when I `M-x color-theme-sanityinc-dark` I get all the correct colors. Then I `M-x set-default-font Consolas-18`, and I get the correct font.

I only use emacs/aquamacs to play with lisps, I usually use Vim. (The emacs key combinations hurt my hands after long use). Am I missing some trick to make the color-theme loading work?

Comment: It looks like lines 76 to 83 are applicable:  https://github.com/purcell/color-theme-sanityinc-solarized/blob/master/color-theme-sanityinc-solarized.el  You can change the colors to whatever you want and then re-byte-compile if needed.  However, I don't know how to neatly change this *elsewhere* without modifying the source code.

Comment: See also the note at the bottom of the readme.md page of the Github repository:  "*Note that, depending on your version of Emacs, the colors in this theme may not be rendered accurately. See, for example, this OS X Emacs bug [ http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=8402 ]. A customizable value color-theme-sanityinc-solarized-rgb-is-srgb controls whether or not RGB color literals used by Emacs are treated as sRGB; consider adjusting this value if the rendered colors don't quite match those on the solarized page.*"  https://github.com/purcell/color-theme-sanityinc-solarized

Comment: I expected some rendering issues. I don't expect the font to be black and then white the next time I run the color-theme. There seems to be something more at work here than a slight RGB difference.

Comment: Hi Ben, I'm curious to know if you ever found a way to solve this problem? I'm asking because I'm having the exact same issue right now. Thanks.

Comment: Nope. Eventually I discovered emacs for Mac (https://emacsformacosx.com/). I'm still using the default theme for that, but I don't know if I failed to customize the colors or just didn't choose to.

Answer (score 0):

Aquaemacs sets the font colour to black in the following file:

~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/customizations.el

If you remove the line that sets the foreground-color to black it should work.